# golang datastore projection query returning empty strings from a populated entity

Tags: google-app-engine, go, projection, google-cloud-datastore

I'm currently working on golang http-based handler running on Google App Engine.

As part of this, I'm trying to pull back all the values I'm interested in via a Projection query looking at a number of fields in a given kind, with the intention of storing each entity load in a struct that mirrors the field types.

This is my query:

`source := datastore.NewQuery("CacheEntry").Project("Campaign",  "Creative", "Impressions", "Operator", "Publisher", "Slot").Limit(50)`

Unfortunately, all I get back from this is empty strings (worse, returning empty strings does not throw an error of any kind so I've only just worked out that it's doing this).

Google's documentation and error reporting is pretty bad when it comes to Datastore so it hasn't been much help. I can see the populated fields on my Datastore viewer in the Google Cloud Console - some fields are actually empty but I should be returning some data at least.

I'm running it in a for loop with the appropriate pointers setup:

```
for t := source.Run(ctx); ; {
    _, err := t.Next(&x)

    log.Println(count)
    if err == datastore.Done {
        log.Println("failed on Datastore:done, count \n")
        log.Println(count)
        break
    }
    if err != nil {
        log.Println("failed on \n")
        log.Println(count)
        http.Error(w, err.Error(), http.StatusInternalServerError)
        break
    }
    //  fmt.Fprint(w, x.Campaign)
    if &x != nil {

        fmt.Fprintln(w, "Strings:\n")
        fmt.Fprintln(w, x.Operator)
        if x.Operator == "" {
            fmt.Fprintln(w, "Campaign string is empty")
        }
    }

    count = count + 1
```

'X' being:

```
type Row struct {
Campaign    string
Creative    string
Impressions int
Operator    string
Publisher   string
Slot        string
```

}

Any ideas where I'm going wrong?

Comment: This is a very useful page [Projection Queries](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/go/datastore/projectionqueries#Go_Indexes_for_projections). In particular: *Projection queries require all properties specified in the projection to be included in a Datastore index*.  Do you have such an index? (Projections return values from indexes rather than the entity itself).

Comment: Yes, although the google docs don't make it clear at all that the sdk will only generate new custom indexes if you run the appengine on a dev_server (goapp serve <app>) beforehand, then deploy with the updated index.yaml. But regardless, they are there.

As it happens, I figured out what the issue is - will post it when I get a chance :)

Answer (score 1):

Figured it out, turns out a number of issues were happening in the background:

- For whatever reason, indexes were not being updated, and the error message indicating this was not being piped to the Http response, hence the query was not running
- After clearing this, I didn't realise that the results I was pulling back included large numbers of events that had blank property values and lacking any kind of ordering, hence they were literally whatever happened to come back before the `.Limit(50)` was being reached ... in that case, the query was running, but I was interpreting the empty string returns as errors when in fact they were correct, just not from the part of the dataset I'd expected - adding Filters for `"<property> >", ""` fixed it

Datastore *sorely* needs better feedback measures than the ones it has. Compared to a lot of similar dbs I've worked with, it's needlessly minimal in it's feedback.

Comment: I don't know if it's because you're using Go or projection queries, but I've found datastore pretty good at hinting at required indexed. The Java runtime, for example, will throw a `DatastoreNeedIndexException` if your query requires an index which hasn't been defined.